# MongoDB: error code - 10068, invalid operator: $oid

Tags: java, mongodb

I tried to query in my mongoDB database using java code, but it throws

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot parse query: { _id: {$oid:"myId"}}

I run same query in mongoDB shell

```
> db.collection.find({ _id: {$oid:"myId"}})
```

but it fails with error

> error: { "$err" : "invalid operator: $oid", "code" : 10068 }

What is the reason of this error and how to solve this problem?

Comment: It's an invalid operator as the error says. Either construct a proper `ObjectID` or supply your own value to `_id` however you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says invalid operator $oid

You can query using one of those

```
db.collection.find({_id: "your_id"});
db.collection.find({_id:ObjectId("5408c3aaca92988d9c70343d")});
```